# JPA EntityManager Create Native Query not returning foreign key data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have two Entities, TableA and TableB, with a many-to-many mapping between them. When I try to select all of table_b using a createNativeQuery I am able to get all table_b's data but I'm not able to reference any of table_a's data.

table_a entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
public class TableA implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "data1")
    private String data1;

    @Column(name = "data2")
    private String data2;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "a_b_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
    private List<TableB> bItems;

    // getters/setters
    public List<TableB> getBItems() {
        if (bItems == null) { bItems = new ArrayList<>(); }

        return bItems;
    }

    public void setBItems(List<TableB> bItems) {
        this.bItems = bItems;
    }
}
```

table_b entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_b")
public class TableB implements Serializable { 

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bItems")
    private List<TableA> aItems;

    // Getters/Setters

    public List<TableA> getAItems() {
        if (aItems == null) { aItems = new ArrayList<>(); }

        return aItems;
    }

    public void setAItems(List<TableA> aItems) {
        this.aItems = aItems;
    }

}
```

NOTE: I'm setting the id manually for TableB before inserting

Processor:

```
@Component
public class ProcessorDAO {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Transactional
    public void process() {

        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction entityTransaction = em.getTransaction();

        try {
            entityTransaction.begin();

            Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_b", TableB.class);
            List<TableB> tableBItems = q.getResultList();

            for (TableB item : tableBItems) {
                // Always 0 here?
                item.getAItems().size();
            }

            entityTransaction.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (entityTransaction.isActive()) {
                entityTransaction.rollback();
            }
            throw e;
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm able to get AItems if I use findAll from TableB's repository but I was trying to get this to work with just the entity manager, not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the foreign key is actually in Table A, selecting only table B, it’s not possible to get the association. You need to join to to table A in the native sql.
Select * from tableB
Join tableA .....